# Spring JPA: try to delete a record in a table with foreign key constraint

Tags: spring, jpa, foreign-keys, delete-row

In a project with Spring Boot and Spring JPA I an enitity FunctionConfiguration with a list of Integer target_device

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "function_configuration")
public class FunctionConfigurationEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_function_configuration")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer idFunctionConfiguration;
    
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "target_device")
    private List<Integer> targetDevice;

}
```

If I try to do a delete with an id of a functionConfiguration

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM FunctionConfigurationEntity fce WHERE fce.idFunctionConfiguration = idFunctionConfiguration")
    void deleteByFunctionConfigurationId(@Param("idFunctionConfiguration") Integer functionConfigurationId);
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: UPDATE or DELETE statement on table "function_configuration" violates foreign key constraint "fk69tox326tcrs3wed1neufb0pv" on table "target_device"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Seems pretty self explanatory. What have you tried?

Comment: I copied your code and run it, no problem. Can you make it delete your tables and create them again. There may be crumbs from previous improvements.